# Search with multi field in asp.net mvc and sql server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Please help me with my problem below:

I have one table in sql server with field: product, customer, year, quantity,...
And i have a search form with 3 textbox: txtprod, txtcust, txtyear and search button

I want my result:

- if all of 3 textboxs null or empty: show all of record
- if 1 of 3 textbox empty, searching with 2 others conditions
- if 2 of 3 textbox empty, searching with  another condition.

Please so me how to write select in sql server or by linq in asp.net mvc

Thanks all so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 0):

assume that value of txtprod, txtcust and txtyear will be filled into prod, cust, and year variables in your controller, and your table will be map to an entity name `Entity`

```
var items = from entity in ModelContext.Entity
            select entity;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prod) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prod))
{
    items = items.Where(item => item.product == prod);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cust) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cust))
{
    items = items.Where(item => item.customer == cust);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(year ) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(year ))
{
    items = items.Where(item => item.year == year );
}

//return your view with filtered data hear. Ex:
return View(items);
```

I hope this can help you with this particular problem

Comment: Thank you so much, I hope you found a good job as programmer (i read your letter or your introduce..)

Comment: Thank you, and I wish you would have a good time at programming :)